# How to manage updates to FCM push tokens?

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am wondering when in an app lifecycle to update the FCM registration token. I am using Firebase React native.

Currently, I send the FCM token to my backend:

- on every app start
- in `onRefreshToken`
- sign in/out actions (to associate a user with the token)

I am wondering whether the above list is comprehensive and whether it contains extraneous update hooks (for instance, I am not certain that updating on every app start is necessary).

Main concerns revolve around:

- what happens if the device loses access to the internet in `onRefreshToken` and the backend fails to be updated about the token refresh?
- what happens if the FCM token gets refreshed when the app is not running? (and, hence, `onRefreshToken` is not invoked?

In summary, what is the officially recommended way to notify backend of updates to the FCM tokens?

Answer (score 1):

because of the complexity of this and the difference depending on the application I have never seen an official recommendation, but a few things to add:

- store the token on the device (e. g. shared preferences) to make sure you always use the latest or ask for the current one each time you need it
- if it is critical you can store the state after an updated token and re-try more often if it has not been successfully transmitted.
- on every app start is usually a good solution as fallback because many things can happen
- consider logout without internet or uninstall. Here you will not remove the token on the server, so the next user could get the message without measures against that.
- implement an update-process on the server to handle error-responses